# Different methods of implementing a specific parsing rule for a compiler

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison

Let's say we have a rule in parsing tokens that specifies:

```
x -> [y[,y]*]
```

Where the brackets '[ ]' mean that anything in them is optional in order for the rule to take place and the * means 0 or more.
e.g it could be:

```
x : (empty) 
  OR
x : y 
  OR
x : y,y
```

as well etc. (the above are examples of input that 'x' rule would be activated, not how the code should be)

I have tried the following that works already

```
x : y commaY
  |
  ;

commaY : COMMA y commaY
       |
       ;
```

I would like to know alternative options in the above that would make it work, if there are any, for educational purposes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The parser rules you give are not bison format and do not seem to implement the grammar you give.  Borrowing your syntax though, you want something like `x -> y OR y COMMA x OR (empty)`

Comment: @BadZen Thanks for the input. I edited a bit my rules to match the syntax so that could help better. Though, I cannot use your rule above, because of the ' * ' specifier that means "0 or more of anything before that" (in our example, "0 or more" of the ,y

Comment: That's exactly what the pseduocode I gave does.  0 or more `,y`.   If you take the first option in the disjunction, you get zero ',y'.   If you take the second, you get one or more.   

Actually tho, there is an error in what I gave, and it's that I allow "y,".    So: `x -> ylist OR (empty)` together with `ylist -> y OR y ylist` is better.  Sorry about that.

Comment: "I would like to know alternative options in the above that would make it work" Does that mean it's not working now? What you've shown looks fine. In what way does it not work?

Comment: @sepp2k It works fine. I am exploring alternatives as well though to understand better how the "optional" and "0 or more" can be implemented together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT my earlier answer was incorrect (as pointed out in the comments), but I cannot remove an accepted answer, so I decided to edit it.*

You will need (at least) 2 rules for `x -> [y[,y]*]`. Here is another possibility:

```
x
 : list
 | /* eps */
 ;

list
 : list ',' y
 | y
 ;
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include the x -> (empty) as well?

Comment: @PavTze done. The empty alternative is only needed if you want `x` to match nothing as well. EDIT, ah yeah you said `[y[,y]*]`, then the empty alternative is needed too.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem @PavTze

Comment: This will allow `, y` without anything before the comma. I'm pretty sure correctly matching zero-or-more elements separated by commas requires two rules.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Good point @sepp2k (and @rici). Can't remove an accepted answer though :(